# Parsing object to remove entries

Tags: json, parsing, object

How would I parse this object, removing all entries where "field"="status", but at the same time retaining the validity of the JSON object (i.e. also removing the extraneous closing braces or brackets at the end of the object?

{"logic":"and","filters":[{"filters":[{"field":"name","operator":"contains","value":"JOHNSON"},{"field":"city","operator":"contains","value":"MILWAUKEE"}],"logic":"and"},{"logic":"or","filters":[{"field":"status","operator":"eq","value":"A"},{"field":"status","operator":"eq","value":"G"},{"field":"status","operator":"eq","value":"O"},{"field":"status","operator":"eq","value":"P"},{"field":"status","operator":"eq","value":"S"}]}]

Comment: Parse it, remove the entries you don't want, then "serialize" what's left.  Doesn't much matter which language you use (though if you're using Java you do have a bewildering choice of JSON toolkits to pick from).

Comment: Incidentally, that JSON is not valid -- you lost a `}` character off the end.

Comment: Parsing in javascript...missing brace was a copy-paste error!

Comment: When posting a question it's important to not miss those characters.  They can completely change the meaning of a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) based on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889893/8379597) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098002/jq-easiest-way-to-recursively-remove-objects-based-on-object-value-condition)

```
def clean(condition):
  if type == "object" then
    if condition
    then empty
    else
    with_entries(
      if (.value|type) == "object" and (.value|condition)
      then empty
      else .value |= clean(condition)
      end
    )
    end
  elif type == "array" then
    map(
      if type == "object" and condition
      then empty
      else clean(condition)
      end
    )
  else .
  end
;

clean(
  has("field") and (.field == "status")
)
```

If `filter.jq` contains this filter and `data.json` contains the sample data then the command

```
$ jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
{
  "logic": "and",
  "filters": [
    {
      "filters": [
        {
          "field": "name",
          "operator": "contains",
          "value": "JOHNSON"
        },
        {
          "field": "city",
          "operator": "contains",
          "value": "MILWAUKEE"
        }
      ],
      "logic": "and"
    },
    {
      "logic": "or",
      "filters": []
    }
  ]
}
```