# jq: easiest way to recursively remove objects based on object value condition

Tags: json, jq

I would like to use `jq` to remove all dictionaries within a JSON "object" (I used that term generally to refer to either an Array or a Dictionary) that

a) contain a key named "delete_me", AND
b) where the key "delete_me" meets some predetermined condition (null, non-zero, true, etc)

Basically, the logic I want to implement is: walk the input, and at each node, if that node is not an Array or an Object, then keep it and move on, otherwise, keep it but remove from it any children that are dictionaries for which either condition a) or b) fail.

Any suggestions?

Sample input:

```
{
  "a": { "foo": "bar" },
  "b": {
    "i": {
      "A": {
        "i": [
          {
            "foo": {},
            "bar": {
              "delete_if_this_is_null": false,
              "an_array": [],
              "another_array": [
                {
                    "delete_if_this_is_null": null,
                    "foo": "bar"
                }
              ],
              "etc": ""
            },
            "foo2": "s"
          },
          {
            "foo": {
              "an_array": [
                {
                  "delete_if_this_is_null": "ok",
                  "foo":"bar",
                  "another_object": { "a":1 }
                },
                {
                  "delete_if_this_is_null": null,
                  "foo2":"bar2",
                  "another_object": { "a":1 },
                  "name": null
                }
              ],
              "an_object": {
                "delete_if_this_is_null":null,
                "foo3":"bar3"
              }
            },
            "zero": 0,
            "b": "b"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

should yield, if the "delete_me" key is `delete_if_this_is_null` and the predetermined condition is `delete_if_this_is_null == null`:

```
{
  "a": { "foo": "bar" },
  "b": {
    "i": {
      "A": {
        "i": [
          {
            "foo": {},
            "bar": {
              "delete_if_this_is_null": false,
              "an_array": [],
              "another_array": [],
              "etc": ""
            },
            "foo2": "s"
          },
          {
            "foo": {
              "an_array": [
                {
                  "delete_if_this_is_null": "ok",
                  "foo":"bar",
                  "another_object": { "a":1 }
                }
              ]
            },
            "zero": 0,
            "b": "b"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE: Here's the solution: Assume the input is in a file 'input.json':

```
jq 'def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

def mapper(f):
  if type == "array" then map(f)
  elif type == "object" then
  . as $in
  | reduce keys[] as $key
      ({};
       [$in[$key] | f ] as $value
       | if $value | length == 0 then .
         else . + {($key): $value[0]} end)
  else .
  end;

walk( mapper(select((type == "object" and .delete_if_this_is_null == null) | not)) )' < input.json
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include examples of the input JSON and the desired output.

Comment: By your definition, what does it mean for an array to have a "key" named "delete_me"? Arrays have integer indices.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jeff, I said I want to remove "all dictionaries" within an object that can be an Array or a Dictionary. I did not say I would remove an array. So the input object (or any node therein) can be an array that contains a dictionary that meets conditions a) and b), in which case I would want to remove that element from the array. How does that not make sense?

Comment: @Jordan, will post later this eve. My current data structure is proprietary so I have to recreate generic data to post.

Comment: I guess the more pertinent question is, what did you mean by "I used that term generally to refer to either an Array or a Dictionary" and what are you referring to? The way you phrased your question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeff's solution may zap too much.  For example, using:

```
def data: [1,2, {"hello": {"delete_me": true, "a":3 }, "there": 4} ]; ];
```

Jeff's solution yields empty (i.e. nothing).

The following may therefore be closer to what you're looking for:

```
walk(if (type == "object" and .delete_me) then del(.) else . end )
```

For `data`, this yields:

```
[1,2,{"hello":null,"there":4}]
```

#### Alternative Solution

If a solution that eliminates the `"hello":null` in the above example is required, then a variant of jq's map_values/1 is needed. Here's one approach:

```
def mapper(f):
  if type == "array" then map(f)
  elif type == "object" then
  . as $in
  | reduce keys[] as $key
      ({};
       [$in[$key] | f ] as $value
       | if $value | length == 0 then . 
         else . + {($key): $value[0]} end)
  else .
  end;

data | walk( mapper(select((type == "object" and .delete_me) | not)) )
```

The result is:

```
[1,2,{"there":4}]
```

Comment: Thanks @peak, the alternative version answers my question using a slight tweak. For the given input/output-- for which I intentionally chose the harder condition of .delete_me being null rather than truthy-- with a minor modification to add ```has("target_key")``` (possibly this renders some of your solution unnecessary but no matter, it works properly as far as I can tell). So for the input/output I posted, replacing ```and .delete_me``` with ```and has("delete_if_this_is_null") and .delete_if_this_is_null == null``` works

Comment: As a variant on your primary solution, I used `empty` instead of `del(.)` and it eliminated nulls in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which uses a recursive function:

```
def clean(condition):
  if type == "object" then
    if condition
    then empty
    else
    with_entries(
      if (.value|type) == "object" and (.value|condition)
      then empty
      else .value |= clean(condition)
      end
    )
    end
  elif type == "array" then
    map(
      if type == "object" and condition
      then empty
      else clean(condition)
      end
    )
  else .
  end
;

clean(
  has("delete_if_this_is_null") and (.delete_if_this_is_null == null)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to do the trick. Are there any advantages / disadvantages to this over the other solutions?

Comment: [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s solution and [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado)'s solution are both good but I wanted to demonstrate how a solution written with explicit recursion could work instead of using `walk/1` because that way the precise details of how/when the condition is used are plain so that the logic could be more easily extended if necessary.   Also I like how this form demonstrates the similarity of `map/1` and `with_entries/1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish in your question but I'm assuming you want to recursively search through a json response and remove json objects that satisfy some condition.

You can do this rather easily with the help of the `walk` filter that will be coming up in a future version of jq, see the implementation in the [source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq).

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;
```

With that, you can filter them out like so:

```
def filter_objects(predicate): # removes objects that satisfies some predicate
    walk(
        if (type == "object") and (predicate) then
            empty
        else
            .
        end
    )
    ;
filter_objects(.delete_me) # remove objects that has a truthy property "delete_me"
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, the logic behind your suggestion seems sound to me but I must be missing something-- as @peak rightly pointed out it zaps too much

Comment: Sorry, was working mostly in the dark on this one. I had no idea how complex your objects would be or if I even interpreted your question correctly. But this could be made to work, I'll make some adjustments.